# Get $$state value from Service Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular so apologies if this has been asked before or is a simple question but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a function in my service like this

```
checkRoomNameStatus: function()
{
    var promises = [];
    var emptyRooms = [];

    DatabaseService.openDB().transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM report_rooms", [], function(a,b){
            for(i = 0; i < b.rows.length; i++){
                console.log('B', b.rows.item(i));
                if(b.rows.item(i).name == '' || b.rows.item(i).name == null){
                    emptyRooms.push(b.rows.item(i));
                }
                promises.push(b.rows.item(i).id);
            }
        });
    });

    return $q.all(promises).then(function(){
        return emptyRooms;
    });
},
```

Its job is to build a list of rooms that do not have a name. I need to wait for the for loop to finish so that it checks all rooms before proceeding, hence the `$q`.

I then need to call my function in my controller and get the results returned.

When I call the function in my controller, like this

```
console.log(SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus());
```

it returns the following object

[image]

Which is great, but how do I then get the value array out of it?

I know its something to do with the way the promise is being returned, but I cant quite crack it!

I've tried the following methods

```
console.log('1',SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus());
console.log('2',SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().$$state.value);
console.log('3',SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().value);
console.log('4',SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().value());
SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().then(function(value){
   console.log(value);
})
```

But I just can't seem to access that value array in my controller! Could someone please explain where I am going wrong and how i'm supposed to correctly approach this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing yourself as to how `$q.all` works. Once the promises have all resolved, you now have access to each of the values that the promises were resolved to in the `then` block of the `$q.all` call. There is a parameter to that `then` call, which is an array of resolved values. Here is an example:

```
$q.all(bunchOfPromises).then(function(data) {
  // data is an array of resolved values (same order as the promises passed in)
  console.log(data);
});
```

So you could instead return this from your service:

```
return $q.all(promises);
```

And then in your controller, access your data like so, as you already tried:

```
SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().then(function(allvalues){
  console.log(allvalues);
})
```

Here is a simple plunkr illustrating how this can work:

https://plnkr.co/edit/xSdi3WS3nlW9ib1QSGRd

Comment: How does the promises get my data from the database query? Do I have to replace `emptyRooms.push(b.rows.item(i));` with `promises.push(b.rows.item(i));` and then return the promises array?

Comment: I don't know what your `DatabaseService` implementation looks like, so I can't really answer that question. If it returns promises, you can just put them directly into your promises array. Otherwise you need to make your own deferred object and either resolve it or reject it with the data from your `DatabaseService`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a promise from a callback-based API, use [$q.defer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api):

```
checkRoomNameStatus: function()
{

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    DatabaseService.openDB().transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM report_rooms", [], function(a,b){
            var allvalues = <some function of (a,b)>
            deferred.resolve(allvalues);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
},
```

Then extract the results with the [`.then`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) method:

```
SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().then(function(allvalues){
  console.log(allvalues);
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Stupid question, where you have the allvalues variable, im assuming i should be populating that the same why I am at the moment, then returning the array through resolve?

Comment: That is correct. Manufacture a promise that resolves to the desired data. The `$q.defer` method creates a "writable" promise. Use the `.resolve` method to write that data.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, will give this a go as soon as i can!

Answer (score -1):

```
something like that:
this.SyncService.checkRoomNameStatus().subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data);
  }, error => { alert("data not found"); });
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain how this works? Why do we need to use `.subscribe`?

Comment: The goal is synchronization. subscribe- listens and waits for information and allows the program to move on rather than wait until the information arrives.
To the best of my knowledge, this is the only way to access information in Angular 2+.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I cant try this method right now but as soon as I get a chance i'll let you know if its worked. Thanks!

Comment: @S_R it looks like you are using `$q`, which is only available in AngularJS. `subscribe` is a part of the Observable pattern used in Angular >= 2. I expect that this won't work for you.

Comment: @james00794 could you possibly suggest how I would do it with AngularJS?